# Converting timeseries data given in timedeltas64[ns] to datetime64[ns]

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I'm given a pandas dataframe that is indexed in timedeltas64[ns].

```
          A            B         C         D                E
0 days 00:00:00    0.642973 -0.041259  253.377516          0.0   
0 days 00:15:00    0.647493 -0.041230  253.309167          0.0   
0 days 00:30:00    0.723258 -0.063110  253.416138          0.0   
0 days 00:45:00    0.739604 -0.070342  253.305809          0.0   
0 days 01:00:00    0.643327 -0.041131  252.967084          0.0   
...                     ...       ...         ...          ...   
364 days 22:45:00  0.650392 -0.064805  249.658052          0.0   
364 days 23:00:00  0.652765 -0.064821  249.243891          0.0   
364 days 23:15:00  0.607198 -0.103190  249.553821          0.0   
364 days 23:30:00  0.597602 -0.107975  249.687942          0.0   
364 days 23:45:00  0.595224 -0.110376  250.059530          0.0
```

There does not appear to be any "permitted" way of converting the index to datetimes. Basic operations to convert the index such as:

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
```

Or:

```
test_df.time = pd.to_datetime(test_df.index,format='%Y%m%d%H%M')
```

Both yield:

```
TypeError: dtype timedelta64[ns] cannot be converted to datetime64[ns]
```

Is there any permitted way to do this operation other than completely reformatting all of these (very numerous) datasets manually? The data is yearly with 15 minute intervals.

Comment: How would you convert a delta to a datetime?  A delta is the difference between two times.  You could add the deltas to a base time (whatever your start is) and then you could get datetimes

Comment: Great, thanks. That's pretty much exactly what I was looking for. Just wasn't able to wrap my head around the timedelta object. If you'd like to reply with this I will accept your answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you cannot convert a `timedelta` object to a `datetime` object because the former is the **difference between two datetimes**.  Based on your question it sounds like all these deltas are from the same base time, so you would need to add that in.  Example usages below

```py
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: now = datetime.datetime.now()

In [3]: delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)

In [4]: print(now, delta + now)
2021-02-22 20:14:37.273444 2021-02-22 20:19:37.273444
```

You can see in the above that the second print `datetime` is 5 minutes after the `now` object